# Which project structure approach should I choose for my web scraping project?

Tags: python, module, hierarchy, directory-structure, project-structure

I want to create script that scrapes the data from different webpages and then load them into database and I want to do this in appropriate way from A to Z. Therefore before I start writing code first I want to divide my little project into smaller chunks so that everything looks clean and clear on the start. From what I know this is called "Modular Programming" and it is a good technique to keep everything well organised. In my project I want to scrape data (job offers) from 4 pages. They are similar but not same so each one of them requires writing different functions. For some I'll just need to scrape data from api and for some I'll need to use more complicated way like Selenium. My question is: how should my folder structure looks like? Is it better to create package let's call it "Websites" and then just add each website as module something like this:

```
websites/
├─ __init__.py
├─ website_1.py
├─ website_2.py
├─ website_3.py
├─ website_4.py
LICENSE
README.md
```

or is it better to split modules into "steps", in the simplest form it would look like this:

```
job_offers/
├─ scraping_data.py
├─ loading_data_into_database.py
├─ __init__.py
LICENSE
README.md
```

In first example each website module has it's own functions, constants variables etc. so everything what concerns each website happens in appropriate module. In the second one, on the other hand, everything is mixed i.e. `scraping_data.py` module contains functions, constants variables for all websites. If none of the above examples are done well please feel free to propose your own solution.

Answer (score 2):

It mostly depends of you or the usage in the organization you're coding at.I would personnaly make a mix of your solutions like so:

```
main.py
loading_data_into_db.py
websites/
├─ __init__.py
├─ website_1.py
├─ website_2.py
├─ website_3.py
├─ website_4.py
LICENSE
README.md
```

where your main would "link it all" and call the different necessary functions.
You can find some advice here :
https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/
but the main advice is: try not to be redundant